# Getting exception while running PowerShell script in C# - The term 'xxxxxx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file'

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, onedrive

I'm running PowerShell script in C# code using this method.

```
PowerShell psExec1 = PowerShell.Create();
string script = File.ReadAllText(downloadPathScript1);
psExec1.AddScript(script);
Collection<PSObject> results2;
results2 = psExec1.Invoke();
```

In downloadPathScript1 I'm giving file path of .ps1 file Even after adding correct command or script I'm getting this exception.

*The term 'Get-Item C:\Program Files\OneDriveLib.dll | Unblock-File' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*

When I run same script in PowerShell it is working as expected. I'm trying to run this script/commands. What could be the cause of this exception?

```
Unblock-File -Path "C:\ODTool - Copy\OneDriveLib.dll"
Import-Module "C:\ODTool - Copy\OneDriveLib.dll"

$Status = Get-ODstatus -ByPath "C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\Test.txt"
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - we can't see how you're using the `PowerShell` object from C#.

Comment: The error message suggests that your script contains something like the following broken call: `& 'Get-Item C:\Program Files\OneDriveLib.dll | Unblock-File'` That is, you're trying to execute a whole pipeline as if it were  a command name or path.

Comment: I tried using `Get-Item C:\Program Files\OneDriveLib.dll | Unblock-File`. Getting exception there as well

Comment: Your script file after being read by ReadallText is missing newline chars and so the 2 lines of text gets merged [Get-Item and Unblock-File ] both end up in same line of script and hence you are getting error.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran: `.ReadAllText()` doesn't strip newlines, and even if that were the problem, the pipeline command would still work.

Comment: @ShivaniG, and what, specifically, is the text of the exception you're getting _now_? Please [edit] your question to show the actual script content (the error message doesn't match the code currently shown).

Comment: @ShivaniG, actually, there's a glaring problem with `Get-Item C:\Program Files\OneDriveLib.dll | Unblock-File`: The `C:\Program Files\OneDriveLib.dll` argument _must be quoted_, given that it contains spaces; e.g.: `Get-Item 'C:\Program Files\OneDriveLib.dll' | Unblock-File`

Comment: @mklement0 If the file was created with an encoding different from system default, there is likelihood of the content assigned to script variable different than intended. As you noted above, the actual script need to be shared by OP, mostly issue is because of whitespaces or line-breaks

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran, yes, character encoding can be a concern - but it would never result in loss of newlines (unless you have a truly exotic encoding). If there were misinterpreted characters, they would show as such in the error message (including misinterpreted whitespace). Again, the original error message unambiguously implies that an entire pipeline was mistakenly executed as if it were the mere _name or path_ of a command. Discussing this problem in terms of newlines or whitespace - or even character encoding, in this particular instance - is a distraction.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you @mklement0. The problem is only because of incorrect placement of the quotes.